# Representing polygon features using arrows that represent direction of orientation?

Tags: symbology, sql, modelling, flood

I have a polygon layer that stores results obtained from simulations run on a hydrological modelling software, ICM.

A particular table within the attribute table of this polygon layer has details about the direction of flow within each feature, in radians.
[image: Column in attribute table representing flow direction]

[image: How direction is represented using radians]

I would like to be able to represent flow directions in QGIS when I load the polygon layer using this data.
Essentially I think, I would need to create a rule-based theme in QGIS by referring to the table "MAXANGLE2D", and provide arrow features for polygons. I would probably have to create a new rule to specify arrow direction based on radians (eg. MAXANGLE2D of 0 means arrow faces east, 1 means it is inclined 57.29 degrees towards North from East, etc.).

So my doubts are:

1. How to use arrows for representing polygon features?
2. How to assign direction to arrows?

I am pretty new to SQL and scripting.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in QGIS without any scripting.  However, you'll need to convert your radians to degrees for this approach - you could add another calculated column.  Then, go to the symbology properties of your layer.  Change the symbol to a marker fill and set the marker type to simple marker.  Then choose the arrow marker.  For the rotation - choose your new degrees column:

[image]

Comment: Or use an expression with `rad_field * 180.0 / <PI>`.

Comment: Or simpler: `degrees(rad_field)`

Comment: Thank you for the inputs!
I had a small doubt regarding this:
 Considering that the other software has a unique system for representing direction (East being 0, and positive values being North etc.), how would I know if that is the same system that exists in QGIS. ?
For example, If the rotation field takes 0 degrees as 'purely North' in QGIS, wouldn't I have to process the calculated degrees before providing the arrow rotations?

Comment: Degrees should be the same across the board.  Also, if you convert the radians to degrees in QGIS, QGIS will certainly know how to use them.